# Golang unit test unmarshal date from json to time.Time property

Tags: go

I am writing a unit test for my GO service and am trying to mock data using a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Description": "Holiday 1",
        "HolidayDate": "2023-01-01T12:00:08+07:00"
    }
]
```

The description field is coming through just fine but the HolidayDate field is coming through as 0001-00-00.

Here is the code that I am using.....what do I need to do in order to get the date field to populate correctly?

```
type Holiday struct {
    HolidayDate time.Time `json:"holidayDate"`
    Description string    `json:"description"`
}

func Ptr1[T any](v T) *T {
    return &v
}

func getMockData() ([]entities.Holiday, error) {
    holidayFilePath := filepath.Join("../adapters/repositories/mocks/testData", "holidays.json")

    mockHolidays, err := UnmarshalFileData[entities.Holiday](holidayFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf(holidayFilePath, err)
    }

    return mockHolidays, nil
}

func UnmarshalFileData[T any](filePath string) ([]T, error) {
    var data []T
    myFile, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return data, err
    }
    defer myFile.Close()
    err = json.NewDecoder(myFile).Decode(&data)
    if err != nil {
        return data, err
    }

    return data, nil
}

func TestMocks(t *testing.T) {
    mockHolidays, err := getMockData()
    holiday := time.Date(2023, time.Month(1), 1, 00, 00, 00, 0, time.UTC)

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("error mocking holiday data:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(mockHolidays[0].HolidayDate.String(), holiday.String())
    assert.Equal(t, holiday.String(), mockHolidays[0].HolidayDate.String())
}
```

I've tried various formats of the date in the JSON and none of them have worked.

Comment: Why are you expecting a `UTC` result from a time with `+07:00`? Your field names also do not match, `"holidayDate" != "HolidayDate"`

Comment: True, thanks for noticing that.  I guess my bigger question is why is the mockHolidays[0].HolidayDate showing as 0001-00-00 instead of 2023-01-01:12:00:08?

Comment: Your json field names do not match, so you are looking at the zero value.

Comment: That did fix it although now the time.Parse is not working! ‍♂️ hol, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05+07:00", mockHolidays[0].HolidayDate.String())

Comment: that's not the format used by [`Time.String`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.String), but you shouldn't be trying to parse the `String()` output anyway because it's really just for debugging since it can also include the monotonic clock value